# How to use NetLimiter to regulate my upload bandwidth load?

Tags: bandwidth, adsl, broadband, netlimiter

Per a recommendation on [why my uploading was killing my downloading](https://superuser.com/questions/375887/should-uploading-a-file-on-dsl-kill-the-download-speed) I've installed [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/). I keep tweaking the configuration and haven't found something I am completely happy with. I couldn't find what I was looking for in the documentation, and contacting their support hasn't gotten any response.

My question is if there is a solution to preventing the upload pipe saturation besides setting an upload limit at just below my theoretical upload limit provided by my ISP (Filtering ACK)? .

Comment: Then the limiting should be performed on your router.

Comment: So what is the best way to filter just one computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there really is much to do wrong in NetLimiter. This is where you set the upload speed limit:

[image]

I never touched anything else when I had to limit my personal bandwidth (but then again I never had the same issue as you). But from looking around the options in NetLimiter, I also don't see what you could possibly do differently in it to adjust limiting behavior.

Comment: So just set a global upload limit of 890 Kbps (below my cap of 893 Kbps) and I should be good? Want to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: I would start with a much lower limit (like 450Kbps) and first verify that is has an impact on your issue. If it has, increase the limit in 50kbps steps until your downloads get noticeably worse. If it has no impact, then this either the wrong solution or NetLimiter isn't capable of doing what you need.