# Why does my fiber download speed increase when testing upload speed?

Tags: fiber, internet-connection

I recently switched to AT&T Gigapower 1GB fiber internet and have discovered a problem where download speeds are slow during normal use. But if I go to Speedtest.net and do a test, when it gets to the upload portion of the test, my concurrent download speed spikes, then suddenly drops drastically again after the test is finished.

How can this be possible, is it a network issue or some throttling added in by the router? I’ll find myself constantly running Speedtest.net just to get large files downloaded faster.

Here is [an example screencast](http://screencast.com/t/pWI4a6am7oR) for reference.

**Download Speed Progression**

1. Before Speed Test (100k/s)
   [image]
2. During Download Speed Test (200k/s)
   [image]
3. During Upload Speed Test (52,450k/s)
   [image]
4. After Speed Test (100k/s)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should uploading a file on DSL kill the download speed?](http://superuser.com/questions/375887/should-uploading-a-file-on-dsl-kill-the-download-speed)

Comment: This is what i ment so if you have no QOS-System its possible that your speed is very slow. There are a lot of more possibilities why that can happen.

Comment: @Stony: **Read** the question. The OP has the problem that his downloads are slow except when he *does* an upload, e.g. with a speed test. This is the exact opposite of what you are talking about.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible each time you conduct a speedtest, and does the speed fluctuate when you don't conduct speed tests?

Comment: Also, have you tried bypassing your router?

Comment: if it's the same with file from other host, other pc and router as @Phil said, i think it's AT&T misconfiguration.

Comment: @Phil Yes the problem is consistent with each speedtest, and no the problem does not fluctuate when I don't hammer the upload speed. I often find myself running a speed upload test just to finish large downloads faster. Also I have not tried bypassing my router, I'm not sure how that would be possible as I have fiber so I would need to at minimum plug directly into the router that converts it to cat5e

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the details of your setup, it is difficult to answer the question “why” with certainty. However, you also ask “How *can* this be possible?”, and I can give you some possibilities. They are not ”fiber“-specific.

1. You are downloading through HTTP, which is a TCP/IP protocol. This protocol is bi-directional, i.e. every packet that is received by your HTTP client is also acknowledged to the server. Thus upload and download are not totally separate(able) traffic.
2. You are downloading from a remote server (vagrantcloud.com), probably not located in your room, building, city, maybe not even state or continent. There are many different network components involved, which have different wire speed and buffer size, and you share them with “the Internet” typically … which you cannot control.
3. You are monitoring the system under observation with a tool running on the system itself. Nobody would do this in professional context (I hope) or at least draw conclusions very carefully from the measurements. It may give wrong results for two reasons.

   - You will influence the behaviour of your host and at least some of the network components which are used by the running download.
   - Your tool may be buggy, because it counts (to be fast and efficient, without decoding/unpacking) incoming packets regardless of their destination or origin, thus assuming that unrelated traffic is a result of its own test traffic.

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) in a pure observer mode to monitor your upload/download traffic and generate the traffic itself by contacting several (geographically separated) servers with other tools (like you did) in order to try to saturate your DSL link. Such a measurement should be rather objective. Again, you would ideally run it on another computer that you put on the same network as your “download test sink.“

PS: Think of your room/housemate and neighbours, who share the bandwidth and will notice that their “internet is slow again today” when you are doing your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the wireshark link, I will check that out later today. I thought about #3 as well, but really concluded that SURELY ATT would not be so nefarious to only give me bandwidth when I am testing for it.

Comment: I don't want to be too formal about "give me bandwidth when I am testing", it is a bit the chicken-or-egg thing. Bandwidth is defined to be the number of IP packets passing within a time interval, divided by the length of this interval. If there is no traffic, there is no bandwidth ;-) What you want to measure is (likely) the maximum bandwidth, hence generate a maximum of packets transmission within a minimum of time.

Comment: Yea absolutely. I guess w/ that in mind my results are simply "takes a much shorter time" to download the same file when an upload speed test is occurring synchronously that it does for the same file to be downloaded when no upload speed test is occuring.

Comment: @Ransom, I am just wondering why you never accepted my question formally. Is there some information still missing?