# Firefox 43: Uploading to Youtube results in DoS behaviour

Tags: firefox, freeze, youtube, upload, denial-of-service

I've been trying to upload a video to my channel today, only to notice that Firefox starts using 100% CPU time on a single core and then suddenly, I and everyone in my household can't connect to the internet at all. During this Firefox itself can't even establish connections to anything even the router's setup page.

Until I cancel upload any pings sent to the modem itself will return times totalling around ~250.0 ms. Any external connection will time out entirely.

When I cancel the upload pings to the modem return to <1 ms response times and outgoing connections will actually go through. Firefox can then browse to other pages without timing out.

This didn't happen to me before about two months ago but I'm not sure if this is a issue with Firefox itself or Google has changed something on their upload page that is causing this behaviour.

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2, with kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic and I am using a wired connection, not wireless.

My addons are: NoScript, Ghostery, µBlock and RefControl.
Flash Player is disabled.

Comment: What is your internet's upload speed like? I noticed a similar behavior when I was home for the summer. University speed is great but when I tried uploading at home it slowed everything to a crawl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should uploading a file on DSL kill the download speed?](http://superuser.com/questions/375887/should-uploading-a-file-on-dsl-kill-the-download-speed)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer after some more digging around. When you are uploading to YouTube, it most likely takes up 100% of your upload speed. I can't say for sure, since you didn't reply to my comment yet, but upload speeds are generally much slower than download speeds.

You would think that uploading shouldn't affect downloading but it does. TCP protocol requires acknowledgement packets to be sent back when downloading. It's difficult to send these ACK packets when your internet's upload is being taken up by the YouTube upload.

Source: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/43869-42-internet-slow-uploading-something